# Can I make a search that shows all results, regardless the user's permissions?

Tags: search

We have a knowledge base with very strict user access permissions. We want users to be able to see all pages in search results, even the ones that they can't access. We want users to be able to see if the content they are interested exists and ask for permission.

Comment: It's usually not allowed by design in solutions designed for Drupal, and standard behavior for solutions that originated away from Drupal, like Solr, Google Custom Search et cetera. Could you tell what's your need? Hacking Views or one of search modules, or integrating 3rd party, possibly paid solution?

Comment: We want to have a default-deny policy, but avoid duplicated content between teams by allowing users to see global search results. That way, they can ask for permission.

Answer (score 2):

You can build this in views. Build your view as you normally would, use an exposed search, then under advanced > query settings > check off "Disable SQL rewriting". This will disable node_access checks as well as other modules that implement hook_query_alter().